# Error trying to get jquery-ui tabs working on a div inside of leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need to get jquery-ui tabs functionality working on a div.  The div lives inside of a few other elements.  It's html bound to a popup marker in a leaflet map.

Here is the html I'm using.  **I know this html works**, as you'll see in the next picture.

Here's a picture of the problem.  The html for both the top div and the div in the popup are **identical.**

Also, my script is called like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $( ".detail-popup-info" ).tabs();
});
```

I did that because I wasn't sure if the actual DOM was finished before that got called, but it looks like it didn't really help.  I think the issue might have something to do with inheriting lots of other properties? When I inspect the css properties, they look totally different.

The top div i'm guessing doesn't inherit anything since I hard defined it in the html page.  The other div, in the popup, is sent in as a string to a function and probably gets shuffled around.

[image: popup error]

Here are the css properties of the broken one:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
cursor: auto;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 400;
height: 100px;
line-height: 16.8px;
text-align: left;
width: 200px;
-moz-font-feature-settings: normal;
-moz-font-language-override: normal;
```

Here are the css properties of the working one:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: url("http://localhost:3001/stylesheets/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: auto auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
border-left-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 9.6px;
height: 100px;
padding-bottom: 1.91667px;
padding-left: 1.91667px;
padding-right: 1.91667px;
padding-top: 1.91667px;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
```

I guess that's kind of the weird part.  The working one has many more css properties than the broken one.  Maybe *jquery-ui* applies some extra properties to it to make it work, but for some reason it isn't applying them to the popup div?

**Update**

So I guess it turns out jquery actually isn't finding the divs inside the popups because they are dynamically added and removed from the DOM every time one is opened or closed.  Here's a picture of the html without the popup opened.  Normally, they reside under `leaflet-popup-pane`, which is empty.

Maybe I'll have to resort to hard-copying the css properties of the working one and applying them manually to the popup divs.

[image]

**Update 2**

Just confirmed it's because the popup html doesn't exist in the DOM.  I did a `setTimeout` on the jquery-ui tabs() function and quickly opened one and it styled it correctly.
But once I close it and reopen it, it's gone again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the tab initialization `$( ".detail-popup-info" ).tabs();` inside of the same event handler that triggers the pop-up window.

Doing it on `load()` means it checks ONCE, after the page's resources have been fully loaded, and if `.detail-popup-info` doesn't exist yet (because it's added after the fact by AJAX or whatever when the user performs whatever action opens the popup window) then it has nothing to initialize.

Instead you want it to check after the popup content has been added to the DOM.  For example if the popup is created by clicking on a button it might look something like this:

```
$('a.popup-button').on('click', function() {
    // ajax call or whatever that inserts the pop-up content
    $( ".detail-popup-info" ).tabs();
});
```

If you're creating the popups with a prepackaged jQuery plugin there may also be an option for a function callback after the pop-up is created/initialized, in which case you'd want to put the call to `.tabs()` in there.

**EDIT:** I took a look at the leaflet.js documentation and you should be able to use the `popupopen` event for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    map.on('popupopen', function() {
        $( ".detail-popup-info" ).tabs();
    });
}
```

I put it in `document.ready` but you should put it just after where ever the code that initializes the map is (the example init code in their documentation is `var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);`).

Comment: Hey this sounds like one of those great solutions that makes me go _why didn't I think of that!_.  But do you know of a way to find out which element fires a _click_ event? It's not a simple button, it's got a long name in the inspector like: _DIV.awesome-marker-icon-darkpurple.awesome-marker.leaflet-zoom-animated.leaflet-clickable_. Except I tried `(that long name).on('click'...)` and it didn't work. Neither did `$('.leaflet-clickable').on('click')`..., nor `$('.awesome-marker-icon-darkpurple')`

Comment: I just skimmed the leaflet.js docs and apparently you can use their custom event `popupopen` which fires whenever a pop up opens.  I'm editing the post now with a new example!

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  That's good, cause it turns out the `.on('click')` wasn't working either because of the exact same problem I was originally having.  The popups don't exist in the html because they are clustered together in a different element until that element is clicked and opened. LOL. I would have had to setup a chain of event listeners..

Comment: Updated the post - try out the new method and let me know how that goes.

Comment: Turns out it is not working as expected.  It styles it properly the first time, but once I close and re-open the popup, the jquery call runs but doesn't do anything :/